# How to set a value by looking up the value based on index in another dataframe and setting the value to a particular row and column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a two df that looks like this:

```
df1:

   site
0  a.com
1  b.com
2  c.com

df2:
   site
0  a.com
```

I am able to extract the index based on this logic:

```
idx = df2.site.isin(df1.site).index
```

I am able to select the value I want to insert into the column like so:

```
df1.site.loc[idx]
```

However when I go to create the new field and pick the row/column I want to insert into, the value that is inserted is 'nan'. Which I can do like this:
    df2.site.loc[[0]] = df1.site.loc[idx]

How do I insert the string from:

```
df1.site.loc[idx]
```

into an existing column in another dataframe by picking the row I want to put it into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), but because need set one value is necessary convert idx to scalar by select first value by indexing:

```
idx = df2.site.isin(df1.site).index[0]
df2.loc[0, 'site'] = df1.loc[idx, 'site']
```

More general solution working if no match values - added default value:

```
idx = df2.site.isin(df1.site).index
df2.loc[0, 'site'] = next(iter(df1.loc[idx, 'site']), 'no match')
```

Maybe is possible use `merge` like:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='site', how='left')
```

Comment: I got error `ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series` with the first answer. Is it possible to do it without the merge, since I only want one field updated?

Comment: @RustyShackleford - I try change idx by `[0]`, but not sure if understand your question.

Comment: Your first answer worked after adding the `[0]` thank you very much!